# docker containers can't talk to each other

Tags: php, docker, nginx, mariadb, containers

I have 3 docker containers that are supposed to talk to each other. A very classic stack with nginx, php-fpm and mariadb.

My stack used to work, but now my containers can't seem to talk to each other anymore, and I don't know what changed. The nginx can't talk to the php-fpm, and the php-fpm can't talk to mariadb.

Here is the docker-compose I use :

```
version: '3'

services:
    web-nginx:
        image: nginx:stable-alpine
        container_name: web-nginx
        restart: always
        ports:
            - "80:80"
    web-php:
        restart: always
        build:
            context: ./php
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        container_name: web-php
    web-mariadb:
        build:
            context: ./mariadb
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        restart: always
        container_name: web-mariadb
        ports:
            - "3306:3306"
```

The content of docker-compose ps :

```
docker-compose ps
   Name                  Command               State           Ports
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
web-mariadb   docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld      Up      0.0.0.0:3306->3306/tcp
web-nginx     /docker-entrypoint.sh ngin ...   Up      0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp
web-php       docker-php-entrypoint php-fpm    Up      9000/tcp
```

My DockerFiles :

```
FROM php:fpm-alpine

ENV USER=docker
ENV UID=1000

RUN adduser \
    --disabled-password \
    --gecos "" \
    --home "$(pwd)" \
    --no-create-home \
    --uid "$UID" \
    "$USER"

[...]
USER docker
```

```
FROM mariadb
RUN echo max_allowed_packet=512M >> /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

The nginx.conf file

```
[...]
http {
[...]
    server {
        listen             80;
        server_name        localhost;

        location / {
            root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index          index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /usr/share/nginx/html;
            include        fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass   web-php:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /script$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

So my php-fpm is supposed to be accessed through port 9000 while mariadb listens to the classical 3306.

Between containers, ping commands are OK, but nc are not (I use nc because telnet is not bundled in alpine images):

```
docker exec -u 0 -it web-nginx sh  #I use -u 0 to be root because otherwise ping is not allowed in the container
/ # ping -c1 web-php
PING web-php (172.22.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.22.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.156 ms

--- web-php ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.156/0.156/0.156 ms
/ # nc -v web-php 9000
nc: web-php (172.22.0.3:9000): Host is unreachable
```

```
docker exec -u 0 -it web-php sh
ping -c1 web-mariadb
PING web-mariadb (172.22.0.4): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.22.0.4: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.199 ms

--- web-mariadb ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.199/0.199/0.199 ms
/var/www/html # nc -v web-mariadb 3306
nc: web-mariadb (172.22.0.4:3306): Host is unreachable
```

Here is the docker inspect command :

```
[
    {
        "Name": "web_default",
        "Id": "e458e63d89e3f6e2c35644aa03f377dc9fba6975b4b8838727b85c57c3b183ba",
        "Created": "2021-01-28T15:00:06.814105722+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.22.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.22.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "af441d802fd26173ea98ca81b85eb48cbea36b65b867df46b6ddb2f5ac484816": {
                "Name": "web-nginx",
                "EndpointID": "6b69e2033b3de50c86161cbec103843de5f83ab53ecebd557ff66ae57adaae04",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "be99788a48d03fb51288aab6373596c41ed8adcbcf8ceaa8ae2ece1e0aa10843": {
                "Name": "web-mariadb",
                "EndpointID": "8f52e8fe97f24161934b9ab3dcdde9da69aeb80388deb3f6442dd089554e30f0",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f1d2aa6a6c2e156416da3ca0424336380b01950d6f0990203a2d0484ad0d04a5": {
                "Name": "web-php",
                "EndpointID": "7e6b95ccb7da5bcdd3754d1965820e429bdf5370cecee0bceb29c79138d36e0e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:16:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.22.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "default",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "web",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.27.4"
        }
    }
]
```

Since ping works between containers, I assume network is correct, but ports are not opened.
Also, I noticed that my containers can't reach internet. Any ping to google or just "outside" is rejected.

I tried restarting the docker service and even reboot my server, but no luck.

I don't know how to troubleshoot this.

Server running centos 8 :
Linux myserver 4.18.0-240.10.1.el8_3.x86_64
Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: If you run `docker-compose ps`, is the PHP application actually running?  Does your Dockerfile change the `CMD` from the base image?

Comment: I added the output of docker-compose ps command above.

my dockerfiles doesn't change the default CMD command. I do have some CMD commands to add some php modules, though